# How to import media library with folder structure between 2 WP sites

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

I am working on a wordpress site, the old site is also on wordpress both latest version. The old site has a large library of media, mostly word documents and PDF's. I have done an export via tools >> export for the media and then imported onto the new site.
The script runs fine but all documents are dropped into the new media library without creating the folders / sub folder so a document that was at /2015/10/document.pdf is now in the media library as document.pdf.
Having transfered 1,000s of posts from the old site it means I have a lot of broken links. Before to write a script to go through the link and re established the links I am wondering am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I have figured out the issue and I am relieved (and ashame) of how easy it was. Under settings >> media the option "Organise my uploads into month- and year-based folders" was unticked, once ticked and re imported the documents are coming as expected! Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: no shame to be had, been working with wordpress for a longtime and i still forget some of its core feature. (human nature we forget).

Answer (score 0):

You could just transfer the upload folder and migrate the Database with a tool such as **WP Migrate DB**

> https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

If there are broken links because of a domain change you can also just do a **search and replace** with a plugin such as.

> https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

This will take in consideration the serialized data in the Database.

Make sure you make a backup of everything before proceeding.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I do not have FTP access to the old site, the client only has WordPress control panel access as an admin

Comment: @user1620090 yeah that makes things a little more complicated, i don't personally know another solution atm. I will look around if i can find something and update the post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the domain but the paths, for instance within posts I have links such as domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/document.pdf but the import did not rebuilt the 2015 or 12 folder and dropped the files straight into the uploads folder, also, when a document had the same name but in different folders the system renamed to document-1.pdf .